# Converting from HSV to RGB with colorsys gives null values

Tags: javascript, react-native, color-wheel

I'm using [react-native-color-wheel](https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-color-wheel) to generate a color wheel.

I have the following code:

```
<ColorWheel
  initialColor="#ffffff"
  onColorChange={color => console.log({color})}
  style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
  thumbStyle={{ height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 30 }}
/>
```

The color is logged but as a HSV value like `{h:-120,s:100,v:100}` (corresponds to Blue on the wheel). But I need a RGB instead. I've attempted, unsuccessfully, to use [colorsys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colorsys), like this:

```
onColorChange={color => {
    var rgb = colorsys.hsvToRgb({color});
    console.log({rgb})
}}
```

Logged: `{r:null,g:null,b:null}`

Why do I get `null` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[link](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c) in this comment with slight modification to let you enter each value independently or all at once as an object

```
/* accepts parameters
 * h  Object = {h:x, s:y, v:z}
 * OR 
 * h, s, v
*/
function HSVtoRGB(h, s, v) {
    var r, g, b, i, f, p, q, t;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, v = h.v, h = h.h;
    }
    i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    f = h * 6 - i;
    p = v * (1 - s);
    q = v * (1 - f * s);
    t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);
    switch (i % 6) {
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }
    return {
        r: Math.round(r * 255),
        g: Math.round(g * 255),
        b: Math.round(b * 255)
    };
}
```

This code expects 0 <= h, s, v <= 1, if you're using degrees or radians, remember to divide them out.

The returned 0 <= r, g, b <= 255 are rounded to the nearest Integer. If you don't want this behaviour remove the Math.rounds from the returned object.

And the reverse (with less division)

```
/* accepts parameters
 * r  Object = {r:x, g:y, b:z}
 * OR 
 * r, g, b
*/
function RGBtoHSV(r, g, b) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        g = r.g, b = r.b, r = r.r;
    }
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b),
        d = max - min,
        h,
        s = (max === 0 ? 0 : d / max),
        v = max / 255;

    switch (max) {
        case min: h = 0; break;
        case r: h = (g - b) + d * (g < b ? 6: 0); h /= 6 * d; break;
        case g: h = (b - r) + d * 2; h /= 6 * d; break;
        case b: h = (r - g) + d * 4; h /= 6 * d; break;
    }

    return {
        h: h,
        s: s,
        v: v
    };
}
```

This code will output 0 <= h, s, v <= 1, but this time takes any 0 <= r, g, b <= 255 (does not need to be an integer)

For completeness,

```
function HSVtoHSL(h, s, v) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, v = h.v, h = h.h;
    }
    var _h = h,
        _s = s * v,
        _l = (2 - s) * v;
    _s /= (_l <= 1) ? _l : 2 - _l;
    _l /= 2;

    return {
        h: _h,
        s: _s,
        l: _l
    };
}

function HSLtoHSV(h, s, l) {
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, l = h.l, h = h.h;
    }
    var _h = h,
        _s,
        _v;

    l *= 2;
    s *= (l <= 1) ? l : 2 - l;
    _v = (l + s) / 2;
    _s = (2 * s) / (l + s);

    return {
        h: _h,
        s: _s,
        v: _v
    };
}
```

All of these values should be in the range 0 to 1. For HSL<->RGB go via HSV.